# fail2ban - how to ban ip permanently after it was baned 3 times temporarily

Tags: centos, customization, fail2ban

Have set up fail2ban service on CentOS 8 by this tutorial: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-protect-ssh-with-fail2ban-on-centos-8/.

I have set up settings similiarly according to tutorial above like this:

```
[DEFAULT]
# Ban IP/hosts for 24 hour ( 24h*3600s = 86400s):
bantime = 86400
 
# An ip address/host is banned if it has generated "maxretry" during the last "findtime" seconds.
findtime = 1200
maxretry = 3
 
# "ignoreip" can be a list of IP addresses, CIDR masks or DNS hosts. Fail2ban
# will not ban a host which matches an address in this list. Several addresses
# can be defined using space (and/or comma) separator. For example, add your 
# static IP address that you always use for login such as 103.1.2.3
#ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8 ::1 103.1.2.3
 
# Call iptables to ban IP address
banaction = iptables-multiport
 
# Enable sshd protection
[sshd]
enabled = true
```

I would like an ip to be baned permanently after it was baned 3 times temporarily. How to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A persistent banning is not advisable - it simply unnecessarily overloads your net-filter subsystem (as well as fail2ban)... It is enough to have a long ban.

If you use v.0.11, you can use bantime increment feature, your config may looks like in this answer - https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/discussions/2952#discussioncomment-414693

```
[sshd]
# initial ban time:
bantime = 1h
# incremental banning:
bantime.increment = true
# default factor (causes increment - 1h -> 1d 2d 4d 8d 16d 32d ...):
bantime.factor = 24
# max banning time = 5 week:
bantime.maxtime = 5w
```

But note if this feature is enabled, it would also affect `maxretry`, so 2nd and following bans from known as bad IPs occur much earlier than after 3 attempts (it'd be halved each time).

Comment: Can you give some examples/scenarios of how permanent banning can unnecessarily overloads net-filter subsystem or fail2ban? I do not see difference between banning a lot of ip's for a long time and banning them permanently. Well... it's obvious that permanently baned ip's list will only increase, but i do not think it would make such difference, do you?

Comment: Nothing is for free. Sure you can use ipset-actions (ipset is better suitable for huge number of IPs by rules checking), but you can measure it by yourself (or google for iptables/ipset performance).
Also note that fail2ban must also handle such huge lists/hash tables inside itself (what would also cause certain server load).
Then think about dynamic IPs, finity of botnets (where some hosts/devices can become fixed, banned by providers by abuses, or changed by owner later), etc and you can answer your Q by yourselves or at least understand why persistent banning doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: I believe for this to work you would also need to increase dbpurgeage in fail2ban.conf accordingly. The default value purge bans after 24 hours.

Answer (score 4):

You can use jail `[recidive]` with `bantime = -1` for permanent ban. Example jail.local:

```
# Jail for more extended banning of persistent abusers
# !!! WARNINGS !!!
# 1. Make sure that your loglevel specified in fail2ban.conf/.local
#    is not at DEBUG level -- which might then cause fail2ban to fall into
#    an infinite loop constantly feeding itself with non-informative lines
# 2. Increase dbpurgeage defined in fail2ban.conf to e.g. 648000 (7.5 days)
#    to maintain entries for failed logins for sufficient amount of time
[recidive]
enabled = true
logpath = /var/log/fail2ban.log
banaction = %(banaction_allports)s
bantime = -1        ; permanent
findtime = 86400    ; 1 day
maxretry = 6
```

General note:
Use SSH key auth and set "AllowGroups" or "AllowUsers" in sshd_config. Most SSH login attempts will stop after a few tries. I also notice on my servers that it is getting less and less after months or years.